# Replacing multiple characters in C#

Tags: c#

How would I write a program, using the `String.Replace` method, that rotates the vowels in a word? Meaning the letter 'a' would be 'e', 'e' would be 'i', 'i' would be 'o', 'o' would be 'u', and finally 'u' would be 'a'.

For example, the word "instructor" would be "onstractur".

Comment: is this an interview question you have received? =)

Comment: Have you tried? How about you go and write some code, and if you have an issue, come back and we'll help you.

Comment: I hope you aren't planning on using this for encryption.

Answer (score 6):

Do the following replacements, in order:

y->@
u->y
o->u
i->o
e->i
a->e
@->a

Of course, @ can be any character that is guaranteed not to occur elsewhere in the string.

Comment: Nice... I was thinking he'd have to use more than one replacement character, but you've got it with only one... nice.

Comment: This one is good. I think my solution is also good in terms of easy to think but can be a lot of code:)

Answer (score 4):

Something like `myString.Replace("u","~").Replace("o","u").Replace("i","o").Replace("e","i").Replace("a","e").Replace("~","a")`

This assumes the string doesn't contain `~` to begin with.

Sorry to post code on a homework question, but some people were saying it couldn't be done with `String.Replace`, and I wanted to make clear that it could . . . the key is just making sure that no two vowels are *simultaneously* replaced with the same thing.  That is, by the time the `o`'s become `u`'s, the `u`'s must already be something else. Likewise, the `u`'s can't become `a`'s until the `a`'s are replaced with something else.  Introducing one additional character (`~` in my case) seemed like the easiest way to deal with this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming this is homework so I'll give you an explaining answer instead of giving you a proper code solution:

I suggest you first create a list or array of all the vowels. Then you look through your original string and check if each character exists in the list of vowels. If it does, then you replace it by the next item in the vowel list (make sure you wrap around at the end)

Comment: This is a homework question. I've made 6 replacements but every time i try to debug, it only executes my last replacement statement. Do you know what i mean?

Comment: so "instructor" is the word im using.
string.replace('a','e')
string.replace('e','i')
string.replace('i','o')
string.replace('o','u')
string.replace('u','a')

then the word instructor would read "asntractar" for some reason. it only executed my last command.

Comment: instructor > 
onstructor >
unstructur >
anstractar

Comment: how would i write it so my final word would be onstractur

Comment: The result of replace is a new string so you should do it like: string result = string.replace('a','e'); result = string.replace('e','i'); etc

Comment: PoweRoy is almost correct, it should be `string result = str; result = result.replace(...);` - you want to place the new string in result, and the replace the chars in that. You keep calling `str.replace`, that's why you only see the last character replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a loop and a switch case will solve your problem easily. Is it a homework? What is your effort in trying

Answer (score 1):

Do a replace on each vowel?
[string.replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). (Do it backwards to prevent wrong replacing)

Backwards will still be a problem without a magic character. See norheim.se answer

> y->@ u->y o->u i->o e->i a->e @->a

Comment: even so :-) the u becomes a (1st step), the a becomes e (last step)

Comment: i dont think that would make a difference because the order wouldnt matter

Comment: and that comment is exactly why you think only the last command will be executed :-)
String.Replace isn't your friend here unless you use a "magic" char (like nordheim.se is suggesting).

Comment: see the only method im allowed to use is String.Replace

Comment: Right, "do it backwards" is the key advice. If you do a->e first, your a's are all gone. Then you do e->i and all your original e's, plus the one's that used to be a's, become i's. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps other is going to be angry because I wrote code fur you. But remark is that I am also newbile in programing world and many times I had questions here on SO which is now looks to me trivial.

Maybe and my code is not good but here is how I will try to do that:

```
using System;
namespace CommandLine{
class Test{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] Args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the word: ");
        string regWord = Console.ReadLine();
        string vowWord = VowelWord(regWord);
        Console.WriteLine("Regural word {0} is now become {1}", regWord, vowWord);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static string VowelWord(string word)
    {
        string VowelWord = string.Empty;
        char replChar;
        foreach (char c in word.ToCharArray())
        {
            switch(c)
            {
                    //'e' would be 'i', 'i' would be 'o', 'o' would be 'u', and finally 'u' would be 'a'.
                case 'a' : replChar = 'e' ;
                    break;
                case 'e': replChar = 'i';
                    break;
                case 'i': replChar = 'o';
                    break;
                case 'o' : replChar = 'u';
                    break;
                case 'u' : replChar = 'a';
                    break;
                default: replChar = c;
                    break;
            }

            VowelWord += replChar;
        }

        return VowelWord;

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but im not allowed to use loops neither

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you aren't going to get very far with string.Replace... you'll end up with all vowels being the same (as you are finding out).  You need to do all of your replacements in one pass.  Your professor gave you a pretty challenging problem, all things considered... especially considering the "no loops" requirements.

You can use String.Replace if you use a placeholder character for one or more characters.  It'll make things a little complicated and silly, but I think that's the point of a lot of beginning programming problems.

Since it is homework, I'll try to stick to hints.  Do a little research into regular expressions and Regex.Replace.  You'll likely find what you are looking for there.

**Edit:** Just saw you can only use String.Replace.  Sorry about that.  You'll have to use a placeholder character.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "instructor";
```

Note that `str.Replace` doesn't change the string. Rather, it returns a *new string*, with the replaced characters.

In effect, writing the following line does nothing, because the result of Replace isn't saved anywhere:

```
str.Replace('a', 'e');
```

To keep the new result you need a variable that point to it:

```
string result;
result = str.Replace('a', 'e');
```

Or, you can reuse the same variable:

```
str = str.Replace('a', 'e');
```

Now, this can be done in a single line, but I wouldn't submit that as homework... A clearer solution, using a temp character, might be:

```
string str = "instructor";
char placeholder = '\u2609'; // same as '☉'

string result = str; //init value is same as str
result = result.Replace('u', placeholder);
result = result.Replace('o', 'u');
// ...
result = result.Replace(placeholder, 'a');

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

A more general solution might be to use an array to cycle the characters. Here, where using an array to hold all characters:

```
string str = "instructor";
string result = str; //init value is same as str
char[] cycle = new char[] { '\u2609', 'u', 'o', 'i', 'e', 'a' };
for (int i = 0; i < cycle.Length; i++)
{
    int nextPosition = (i + 1) % cycle.Length;
    result = result.Replace(cycle[nextPosition], cycle[i]);
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The advantage of this is that it can easily be expanded to other characters, and avoid some repetition. Note that `(i + 1) % cycle.Length` is a common trick to cycle an array - `%` represents the `mod` operator, so this keeps me in the array, in the right position.

Comment: +1 for the "(i + 1) % cycle.Length is a common trick to cycle an array"

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is `String.Replace`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit like homework.

If you post code showing what you are trying to do and where you are having problems you are more likely to get an answer, as at least it shows you've attempted to find a solution.